# how to stop generating code on a particular button?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i stop jQuery mobile to apply styles to my specific form elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108578/how-can-i-stop-jquery-mobile-to-apply-styles-to-my-specific-form-elements)

I am trying to create an input button for my own use in my web-application thats using jquery framework. But when I see the html code in browser, the framework is generating some wrapper code around that input, how to prevent that code to be not generated?

my code:

```
<input type="button" value="off" class="toggle-btn" id="toggle-btn1" />
```

Generated output:

```
<div data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-c">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">off</span>
    </span>
    <input type="button" id="toggle-btn1" class="toggle-btn ui-btn-hidden" value="off">
</div>
```

Comment: Post your JS code, probably something you call is causing such behavior.

Comment: Your button is still there, it's just hidden. But he will be triggered when a click is made on the replacing div. Check  jquerymobile docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `data-role="none"`

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/#docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Comment: Oh MAN, I've been looking for this for hours, THANK you!

Answer (score -1):

You're using the jQuery Mobile framework?

The generated output is a way for the framework to create those functional buttons on the webpage. They hide all the HTML really required and make it simple by just getting you to specify a class name. Is this wrapper HTML doing something you don't like?

I don't understand what you mean about input button? Do you want a button.. or an input field?
e.g.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
<label for="name">Text Input:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""  />
```

Comment: I just want an input field without extra markup generated by jquery-mobile

Comment: -1 for answering without reading question.

Comment: Hmm okay. I got confused. However. I still believe I answered your question. jQuery mobile libraries will automatically create the wrapper code you see when you look at the HTML.