# How can I make JQuery Mobile ignore elements by css class?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I have a standard link I want to style my own way within a footer like so:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="somelink.html>some link</a>
</div>
```

I want the `<a>` tag to stay as is and not be transfered into this:

```
<a href="somelink.html" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-up-a">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">some link</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Is there some kind of attribute I can add to the link to stop JQM generated this themed code? I need something similar to the `data-role="none"` class explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209369/how-to-stop-generating-code-on-a-particular-button) (but not for a form element)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's just as you said, add the data-role="none" attribute to the anchor tag.

- Live Example w/ data-role="none" : http://jsfiddle.net/CrBdX/2/
- Live Example wo/ data-role="none" : http://jsfiddle.net/CrBdX/1/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div id="footer" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="somelink.html" data-role="none">some link</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes of course - I was using the wrong version (alpha 2) and this has been fixed in the latest (alpha 4) :/

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.  This is especially helpful when you want to "turn off" JQuery Mobile UI for certain elements. Ex:    @Html.RadioButtonFor(g => g.myProfile.Gender, "Female", new { data_role = "none" }) Female