# JQuery Mobile: how to neutralize JQM on one element?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

**Given my html structure as:**

```
<body>
  <div data-role="page" data-theme="b">
  <header>My header</header>
    <div data-role="content">
    My page-specific content
    </div>
  <footer>My footer</footer>
  </div><!-- page end-->
</body><!-- body end-->
```

I want JQM.js (and JQM.css) to work on the header, footer, but not on the page.

**.1. How to neutralize JQM.js on this single `<div data-role="content">` element ?**

---

**Optional:** 2. If possible, how neutralizing JQM.css on same element ?

Comment: May be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031335/

Answer (score 2):

Change `data-role="content"` to `data-role="none"`

Comment: **Note:** It's not inherited. Child elements are *NOT* neutralised.